# how to return multi values from a function used in query as a parameter?

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters

I want to lookup in some values , 
These values returned in a string from a global function "getColors". 

This is my query:

SELECT Colors.* 
FROM Colors
WHERE ((Colors.Description) In (getColors()));

And this is the function:

Public  Function  getColors()  As  String 
                getColors = "BLUE , GREEN"
End Function

when i return a one word string from "getColors()" as "BLUE", 
the query give me a one record as a result,
But when i return more than one word, As "BLUE , GREEN" , The query returns a one empty record,
 Where is the problem !

Comment: What is the function code?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I reedit the question, Added function code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `getColors` returns a string such as "Blue" or even "Blue, Purple, Green" you can use `INSTR` to check.
The `IN` SQL keyword would be used if your values were returned as records in a single field.

```
SELECT *
FROM   Colors
WHERE  InStr("Green,Purple", Description)>0
```

or in your case:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Colors
WHERE  InStr(getColors(), Description)>0
```

**Edit:**
Without seeing your function code it's hard to tell, but the answer given by @ErikvonAsmuth is probably better suited - using `InStr` will add an extra layer to the question "Is my colour in this list of colours?  True or False?"
Eriks answer does the check in the function (although I'd use a `SELECT CASE`), while yours returns the colour and then it checks for TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: really helpful answer, It worked now as a want, The InStr() function do the trick, Thanks Darren,  I wish if i can vote but my reputation is less than 15, Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. A function can only return a single variable. While one could return an array, SQL doesn't support that. Instead, you pass the value you want to compare as an argument to the function, and return a boolean

For example:

```sql
SELECT Colors.*
FROM Colors
WHERE CheckColors(Colors.Description)
```

And then, as code:

```
Public Function CheckColors(strColor As String) As Boolean
    If strColor = "Blue" Or strColor = "Green" Then
        CheckColors = True
    Else
        CheckColors = False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstand me, My function return  one string variable, But this string holds multi values, The InStr() function suggested by Darren do the trick.

Comment: I understand your question just fine. The solution by Darren is dirty, and will cause problems with overlapping names (e.g. green will match olivegreen). My point is that you should do the comparison in the user-defined function, and not in SQL. Then you don't have this problem. You might notice that even Darren says he prefers my solution, though he'd adjust it a bit

Comment: Understood Erick, But the values i will compare  a lot , Also if i do your solution i will have to make a loop to execute the query for each boolean  result. eg: for each function return, OK , I will take care of overlapping and  i appreciate your effort , Thank you.